# Python - Create Array from List?!

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
    means = [[2, 2], [8, 3], [3, 6]]
    cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
    N = 20
    X0 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[0], cov, N)
    X1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[1], cov, N)
    X2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[2], cov, N)
    X = np.concatenate((X0, X1, X2), axis = 0)

    Y = X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 3, replace=False)]
    A = [X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 3, replace=False)]]
    B = A[-1]

    print(Y), print(type(Y))
    print(A), print(type(A))
    print(B), print(type(B))

     >>> 
    [[3.58758421 6.83484817]
     [9.10469916 4.23009063]
     [7.24996633 4.0524614 ]]
    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    [array([[3.22836848, 7.06719777],
           [2.33102712, 0.96966102],
           [2.06576315, 4.84061538]])]
    <class 'list'>
    [[3.22836848 7.06719777]
     [2.33102712 0.96966102]
     [2.06576315 4.84061538]]
    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Can you help me explain

1. What does `X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 3, replace=False)] mean`? 
   Is `np.random.choice()` supposed to return a new array?
2. Why Y and A return different results?
3. Is B supposed to return the last element in the list?

Thank you!

Comment: just google it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find the docs for scipy and numpy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) as referenced in the comments.
2. Y is a `numpy.ndarray` object, and A is a `list` object. This is due to the `[brackets]` you have when you create A. The first and only element in A (the list) is Y (the array).
3. B does return the last element in the list. The last element in the list is the array object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) on numpy.random.choice to find out exactly how the function works. In this instance, it essentially chooses 3 random indices from the numpy array X.

```
Y = X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 3, replace=False)]
```

This line can be thought of like this: Choose 3 random values from X, and create a new numpy array containing those values, and call it Y.

```
A = [X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 3, replace=False)]]
```

Then, define a regular python list. This is a list with only one element. That one element is a numpy array of 3 random values from X. The key concept is that A only has one element. However, that one element happens to be an array, which itself has 3 elements.

```
B = A[-1]
```

Finally, you are right that this returns the last element of A, and calls it B. From above, we know that A only has one element, an array of 3 elements. Therefore, that array is the last element of the list A.

The major takeaway is that python allows you to have lists of lists, lists of numpy arrays, etc.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks ;)